# What sort of license would I need to fly a small drone (e.g. DJI Spark) in the Israeli Golan?

Tags: regulations, dji-spark

I live in the Israeli Golan. There are a bunch of military bases around, and regulations about drones - since, naturally, you don't want to get your drone shot down or cause a national security incident.

I'm wondering about a *small* drone - specifically, the [DJI Spark drone](https://www.dji.com/spark). It's 143×143×55mm in size, and weighs 300g.

**What sort of license would I need to fly this drone in the Israeli Golan?**

Answer (score 2):

The rules for drones in Israel are listed in [this government](https://caa.gov.il/index.php?option=com_docman&view=download&alias=6681-what-is-the-law-of-drone-flying-in-israel-1&category_slug=2015-10-13-06-38-50-7&Itemid=669&lang=he) document, no license is needed for personal flights but these rules must be followed *(minor grammar corrections)*:

> - Read carefully the flight manual of your drone
> - Fly with a full line of sight visual contact
> - Do not fly over 50 meters altitude
> - Do not fly closer than 2 km from any airport or airfield
> - Join Israeli flight club for model aeroplanes http://www.aeroclub.org.il/
>
> **Do not:**
>
> - fly nearby any aeroplanes
> - Do not fly above people and buildings, at least 250 meters range from them
> - Do not fly in a no-fly zone
> - Do not fly carelessly in a way that will cause danger for human life
> - Do not fly commercial flights without a license

As to if you can fly in the Israeli Golan, you should be fine. Specific no-fly zones are listed [on this map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1BTPbRwweccCVvYlvWnAhwA5-Kfw&ll=32.97939123119757%2C36.08287839008699&z=9).